# How do I rewrite part of an entity framework expression tree for re-use server side? (SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have the following code below, which is part of a larger expression tree, and it strikes me that I should be able to write a method/expression that can be reused to obtain the Contacts list without all this duplicated code.

Is there a way I can write something like this in each part of the tree:

```
Contacts = getContactEmailAndPhones(cnt)
```

or

```
Contacts = ... select getContactEmailAndPhones(cnt)
```

and not have to duplicate the code as below?

```
   Company = com != null
            ? new PM_VC<Company>()
            {
                Vendor = com,
                // Get all the contacts mapped to the vendor
                Contacts = (from m_cc in db.M_CCs
                            join cnt in db.Contacts on m_cc.ContactID equals cnt.ContactID
                            where m_cc.CompanyID == com.CompanyID
                            select new PM_Contact
                            {
                                Contact = cnt,
                                Emails = (from ea in db.EmailAddresses
                                          where ea.ContactID == cnt.ContactID
                                          select ea).ToList(),
                                Phones = (from ph in db.Phones
                                          where ph.ContactID == cnt.ContactID
                                          select ph).ToList(),
                                Primary = m_cc.PrimaryContact
                            }).ToList()
            }
            : null,

   Individual = ivend != null
            ? new PM_VC<Individual>()
            {
                Vendor = ivend,
                // Get all the contacts mapped to the vendor
                Contacts = (from m_vc in db.M_IVCs
                            join cnt in db.Contacts on m_vc.ContactID equals cnt.ContactID
                            where m_vc.IVid == ivend.IVid
                            select new PM_Contact
                            {
                                Contact = cnt,
                                Emails = (from ea in db.EmailAddresses
                                          where ea.ContactID == cnt.ContactID
                                          select ea).ToList(),
                                Phones = (from ph in db.Phones
                                          where ph.ContactID == cnt.ContactID
                                          select ph).ToList(),
                                Primary = m_vc.PrimaryContact
                            }).ToList()
            }
            : null,

   Joint = jvend != null
            ? (from m_ivjv in db.M_IVJVs
               join ijven in db.Individual on m_ivjv.IVid equals ijven.IVid
               where m_ivjv.JointID == jvend.JointID
               select new PM_VC<Individual>()
               {
                   Vendor = ijven,
                   // Get all the contacts mapped to the vendor
                   Contacts = (from m_vc in db.M_IVCs
                               join cnt in db.Contacts on m_vc.ContactID equals cnt.ContactID
                               where m_vc.IVid == ijven.IVid
                               select new PM_Contact
                               {
                                   Contact = cnt,
                                   Emails = (from ea in db.EmailAddresses
                                             where ea.ContactID == cnt.ContactID
                                             select ea).ToList(),
                                   Phones = (from ph in db.Phones
                                             where ph.ContactID == cnt.ContactID
                                             select ph).ToList(),
                                   Primary = m_vc.PrimaryContact
                               }).ToList()
               }).ToList()
            : null,
```

I presume the easier method is to replace the part after the select (since there are different mapping/join table references to obtain the relevant `cnt` object. Any suggestions on how to do this so it can be executed server-side, rather than in the client code, would be greatly appreciated!

To clarify, while I could leave the code as-is, I want to use the parts that obtain email and phones in another method to get those details for specific vendor IDs. In this method, it's using a join, and it would be unnecessary duplication and maintenance to have yet another instance.

I am using entity framework core 5 and c#.

Comment: Why use JOINs in the first place? If the `Contact`, `EmailAddress` and `Phone` entities had proper relations between them there would be no need for `JOIN` or nested `from...` queries. EF itself would generate the necessary joins based on the relations. There wouldn't be any need for extra queries to load the `Emails` and `Phones` properties, they'd already be properties of `Contact

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah, I see I can get the contact from the mapping object (i'm using lazy loading, so I'd have to specify to load those properties) but the email and phones depend on contact, not the other way around - it would still require duplicated code, however, which is my primary concern at this point.

Comment: I should note that Emails and Phones depend on Contact, but contact doesn't have Emails and Phones as a navigational property, since ContactID is the foreign key for Email and Phone. Multiple Email and Phone can be mapped to a Contact.

Comment: That doesn't mean it can't have those properties. If it does, there won't be any need for all those joins. That's the whole point of using an ORM - to work with objects and relations instead of SQL

Comment: well... it seems like you're prompting for a code review\refactor here based on the notion of an easier to use helper method.  I don't think this is a good question for SO in that respect. In addition, you're using some incorrect terminologies.  (client-side\server-side has nothing to do with this framework, you mean lambda expression when speaking of expression trees). also, nothing specific to sql in this question.  It could still be relevant (not sure how), but I am getting the impression you mean 'query expression'.

Comment: It looks like I was barking up the wrong tree, after all. While I'd still like to discover how to use a query expression like this, implementing navigation properties in the parent class has helped reduce the joins. Thanks, @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: I think you're right @BrettCaswell - with the other suggestion about navigation properties, I'm able to reduce the joins, but reusing the query expression for the projection for a given contacts list would be useful as there are other methods that need to call the same structure.